# Error when using pandas to convert dates on the dataframe or when reading the csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I need to import a csv file using pandas that have a date field in the format 'year.decimal day' such as '1980.042' which would be in the format 'DD/MM/YYYY', '11/02/1980'.

File sample:

```
data
1980.042
1980.125
1980.208
1980.292
1980.375
1980.458
1980.542
1980.625
1980.708
```

Using pd.to_datetime I can transform it like this:

```
d = '1980.042'
print(pd.to_datetime(d, format = '%Y.%j'))
```

Output:

```
1980-02-11 00:00:00
```

My first attempt was to read the file and convert the dataframe column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv')
print(df.dtypes, '\n\n', df.head())
df['data'] = p
d.to_datetime(df['data'], '%Y.%j')
```

Output:

```
data    float64
dtype: object 

        data
0  1980.042
1  1980.125
2  1980.208
3  1980.292
4  1980.375

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datas.py", line 4, in <module>
    df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], '%Y.%j')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 451, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 368, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 492, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 513, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
AssertionError
```

The second attempt was to transform the column into a str and then a date:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv')
print(df.dtypes, '\n\n', df.head())

df['data'] = df['data'].astype(str)
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], '%Y.%j')
```

Output:

```
data    float64
dtype: object 

        data
0  1980.042
1  1980.125
2  1980.208
3  1980.292
4  1980.375

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datas.py", line 6, in <module>
    df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], '%Y.%j')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 451, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 368, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 492, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 513, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
AssertionError
```

Then I realized that for some internal floating point issue the data was getting more than three decimal places. So I rounded it up to just three decimal places before convert:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv')
print(df.dtypes, '\n\n', df.head())
df['data'] = df['data'].round(3).astype(str)
print(df.dtypes, '\n\n', df.head())
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], '%Y.%j')
```

Output:

```
data    float64
dtype: object 

        data
0  1980.042
1  1980.125
2  1980.208
3  1980.292
4  1980.375

data    object
dtype: object 

        data
0  1980.042
1  1980.125
2  1980.208
3  1980.292
4  1980.375

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datas.py", line 8, in <module>
    df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], '%Y.%j')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 451, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 368, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 492, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 513, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
AssertionError
```

Finally, I looking at the pandas documentation and in some forums that I could define the data type when reading the file and also apply a lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd

date_parser = lambda col: pd.to_datetime(str(col), format = '%Y.%j')

df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv', parse_dates = ['data'], date_parser = date_parser)

print(df.dtypes, '\n\n', df.head())
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 377, in _convert_listlike
    values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx", line 188, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datas.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv', parse_dates = ['data'], date_parser = date_parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1921, in read
    names, data = self._do_date_conversions(names, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1675, in _do_date_conversions
    self.index_names, names, keep_date_col=self.keep_date_col)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 3066, in _process_date_conversion
    data_dict[colspec] = converter(data_dict[colspec])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 3033, in converter
    return generic_parser(date_parser, *date_cols)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/date_converters.py", line 39, in generic_parser
    results[i] = parse_func(*args)
  File "datas.py", line 3, in <lambda>
    date_parser = lambda col: pd.to_datetime(str(col), format = '%Y.%j')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 469, in to_datetime
    result = _convert_listlike(np.array([arg]), box, format)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 380, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 347, in _convert_listlike
    errors=errors)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 5
```

Anyway, nothing works, has anyone been there? Any suggestions for doing the file reading with the correct data type or for converting the column on the dataframe?

Comment: Try: `pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype=str)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `datetime` module. You can try the following code:-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv',dtype=str)
df["data"] = df["data"].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y.%j'))
```

However this code will fail. Because your data has problem.

```
1980.375
1980.458
1980.542
1980.625
1980.708
```

For these values if you see the number of days is greater than 365 (3 decimal places), which is not possible and thats why it will throw error.

Hope this helps!!

You can try the following code as well which is a lot cleaner:-

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime 
date_parser = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y.%j') 
df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv', parse_dates = ['data'], date_parser = date_parser) 
print(df)
```

Comment: I really hadn't realized the problem with the data.
Removing those with decimal parts greater than 365, I tested your idea.
Unfortunately, it returns the value of the first line for all dataframe lines.
But I used the datetime module in a lambda function when reading the file as follows:

 import pandas as pd
 import datetime
 date_parser = lambda col: datetime.datetime.strptime(col, '%Y.%j')
 df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv', parse_dates = ['data'], date_parser = date_parser)
 print(df)

Comment: I have modified the code. It should work now.
```df["data"] = df["data"].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y.%j'))```

Comment: added your code as well. that also works. I think that's more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I really hadn't realized the problem with the data.

Removing those with decimal parts greater than 365, I tested Tuhin Sharma's idea.

Unfortunately, it returns the value of the first line for all dataframe lines.

But I used the datetime module, as suggested by Tuhin Sharma, in a lambda function when reading the file as follows:

Sample file:

```
data
1980.042
1980.125
1980.208
1980.292
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
date_parser = lambda col: datetime.datetime.strptime(col, '%Y.%j')
df = pd.read_csv('datas.csv', parse_dates = ['data'], date_parser = date_parser)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        data
0 1980-02-11
1 1980-05-04
2 1980-07-26
3 1980-10-18
```